# PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /var/www/zephyr/library/XenForo/Application.php on line 1534

Tags: php, linux, apache2, xenforo

[Sat Aug 12 02:21:28.993810 2017] [php7:notice] [pid 20352] [client :14302] PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /var/www/zephyr/library/XenForo/Application.php on line 1534

```
    /**
 * Gets the current memory limit.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public static function getMemoryLimit()
{
    if (self::$_memoryLimit === null)
    {
        $curLimit = @ini_get('memory_limit');
        if ($curLimit === false)
        {
            // reading failed, so we have to treat it as unlimited - unlikely to be able to change anyway
            $curLimit = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (substr($curLimit, -1))
            {
                case 'g':
                case 'G':
                    $curLimit *= 1024; //This is line 1534
                    // fall through

                case 'm':
                case 'M':
                    $curLimit *= 1024;
                    // fall through

                case 'k':
                case 'K':
                    $curLimit *= 1024;
            }
        }

        self::$_memoryLimit = intval($curLimit);
    }

    return self::$_memoryLimit;
}
```

Not quite sure how to fix this one, kind of stumped, I pointed out line 1534

Comment: My guess is $curLimit = @ini_get('memory_limit'); is set to something like 1M. So check what $curLimit is.

Comment: `var_dump($curLimit)`

Answer (score 2):

You are multiplying a string with an integer in `$curLimit *= 1024;`. Because `$curLimit` equal (for example) `512M`. So what you have to do is **delete the last character** :

```
$curLimitNumber = substr($curLimit, 0, -1);//Will extract the number (512 FROM 512M)
switch (substr($curLimit, -1))
        {
            case 'g':
            case 'G': 
                $curLimitNumber *= 1024;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, however I fixed the issue, apache2 was trying to load php5 and php7 at the same time which caused it to broke, unloading php5 fixed this issue

Comment: @ItsDezi you did not get this notice because of Apache. Chances are you just disabled notices now. Or your php7.ini is not using the shorthand notation for memory_limit

Answer (score 0):

Your `$curLimit` comes from

```
$curLimit = @ini_get('memory_limit');
```

Quoting http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit:

> When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used.

And quoting [that FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes) mentioned in the docs:

> The available options are K (for Kilobytes), M (for Megabytes) and G (for Gigabytes; available since PHP 5.1.0), and are all case-insensitive. Anything else assumes bytes. 1M equals one Megabyte or 1048576 bytes. 1K equals one Kilobyte or 1024 bytes. These shorthand notations may be used in php.ini and in the ini_set() function.

The code you show is checking for the last char in the `$curLimit` value taken from `memory_limit`:

```
switch (substr($curLimit, -1))
```

This means, it is already anticipating the shorthand notation. In the `case` blocks, it's checking for k, g, m and so on (the shorthands) and then expands `$curLimit` to the actual bytes.

When you do

```
$value = "1M";
$value *= 1024;
```

the result will be 1024, but you'll get the Notice you get, because "1M" is not a well formed numeric value, but just a string. What PHP does in this case is to [type juggle](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the number up to the first non-numeric char, e.g. it treats "1M" as integer 1. So, the code will work, but it's sloppy. Hence the notice.

If you want to get rid of the notice, you'll have to strip the shorthand from `$curLimit` or cast `$curLimit` to int or pass it to [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) before multiplying it.

There is a bug report about this in the XenForo forums:

- https://xenforo.com/community/threads/php-7-1-0-upgrade-error.123699/

Comment: Thank you everyone, however I fixed the issue, apache2 was trying to load php5 and php7 at the same time which caused it to broke, unloading php5 fixed this issue